# where can we download the oracle.xml.diff package jar. I need to import in a java program of mine

Tags: java, xml, eclipse, oracle

I am writing a java program in eclipse. It needs to import import oracle.xml.diff.XmlUtils;
oracle.xml.diff.Options;

But eclipse is not recognizing it and also I cannot find these jars online. Can anyone refer me any site from where I can download these jars.

Comment: Have you tried downloading Oracle's XDK libraries? http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/index-100632.html . I guess, you might find it there.

Comment: Is there any jar of the libraries? I am unable to find any.

Answer (score 0):

You need xml.jar file that ships with Oracle Database 12C or later.

Download the database from [here](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/enterprise-edition/downloads/index-092322.html) and install it.

xml.jar can be found in /lib directory under the shiphome directory.

Sorry there's no easier way to get the jar at the moment.

Answer (score -1):

After installing the above database then `xml.jar` is present at:

`D:\app\"username"\virtual\product\12.2.0\dbhome_1\sqldeveloper\modules\oracle.xdk`

Type the "username" otherwise you may not able to open it.
I installed my database in the `D:` so it displays that.

First, open the installed folder and then move to the virtual, product, then 12.2.0 or the version you downloaded then select `dbhome_1` and select sqldeveloper and then modules and then `oracle.xdk` there you can find `xml.jar`.